# how to make bootstrap popover content depends on clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I i want to display a bootstrap popover that contains informations about the clicked anchor  . the anchor was added dynamically . this is the anchor code
html ::

```
<a id='reserveAnchorClone' offsetx="0.4882005899705015" offsety="0.41685144124168516" data-container="body" rel='popover'  data-placement="left" class="reserveAnchor"  >37</a>
```

js::

```
  var popOverSettings = {
        placement: 'left' ,
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        selector: '.reserveAnchor',
        content: function(){return $('#popover_content_wrapper_add').html();},
    }
$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
```

I want to display offsetX offsetY attribute of anchor in the popover , how can i do this.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: i'm using bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are adding the anchor dynamically just add something like this:

```
var popOverSettings = {
    tite: $('#reserveAnchorClone').attr('id'),
        content: function(){return $('#reserveAnchorClone').attr('offsetx') + "<br/>" + $('#reserveAnchorClone').attr('offsety');},
    }
$('#reserveAnchorClone').popover(popOverSettings);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3g4h/3/

Comment: @user2784013 my bad try the link again. I linked the wrong one.

Comment: yes i't a working exemple , but look at this url http://jsfiddle.net/aG7gt/ 
i made a modification so i can apply it in my case , it seems that it doesn't work. Can you show me what's wrong with it .

Comment: @user2784013 try this one http://jsfiddle.net/aG7gt/1/ and also mark the answer as correct if it helped you!